# DateDiff in SQL ODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, odbc, datediff

I'm using a datediff in SQL.  It returns records when run directly in sql server 2008, but when I try and run it through ODBC it doesn't bring up an error, but it returns no rows.

```
SELECT  mc_id, mc_date_entered,
 COUNT([mv_value]) total
FROM MarkbookValue t1
    RIGHT JOIN MarkbookColumn t2 ON t1.mv_column_id = t2.mc_id
WHERE mc_module_id = '703000026609358' 
    AND DateDiff(dd, mc_date_entered, '2012-10-05 20:00:00') = 0
    AND mc_type = 'KEF'
    AND mc_entered_by = 'A.ADMIN'
GROUP BY
    mc_id, mc_date_entered;
```

Getting rid of the DateDiff lets the function run correctly, but I'd obviously like to have it in there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be your date format that is interpreted differently. Try `'2012-10-05T20:00:00'` instead,

Comment: the 'T' solved it.  Fancy adding this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is not a safe date format to use for a date time literal value in SQL Server. Depending on `SET DATEFORMAT` your month and day part might be switched.

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` and `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` are safe to use regardless of `SET DATEFORMAT`.

To get the rows for a specific date I suggest that you do as in the answer provided by [@RichardTheKiwi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12779226/569436) or if you are in SQL Server 2008 you can cast your column to date to remove the time part.

```
where cast(mc_date_entered as date) = '2012-10-05'
```

`YYYY-MM-DD` **is** safe for data type `date`.

Comment: Didn't know that `YYYY-MM-DD` was safe to use with `date`, thanks.

Comment: @AndriyM - Thanks for the edit. [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS is also safe for datetime2](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/290971/deprecate-the-date-literal-interpretation-yyyy-dd-mm-except-in-compatibility-modes-90)

Answer (score 3):

I would almost always write dates in ISO-8601 format, the one without dashes being YYYYMMDD.
Just would like to also point out that if you want your query to use an index on `mc_date_entered` and remain [SARGABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), you'll want to rewrite it like this.

```
SELECT  mc_id, mc_date_entered, COUNT([mv_value]) total
FROM MarkbookValue t1
RIGHT JOIN MarkbookColumn t2 ON t1.mv_column_id = t2.mc_id
WHERE mc_module_id = '703000026609358' 
    AND mc_date_entered >= '20121005'
    AND mc_date_entered <  '20121006'
    AND mc_type = 'KEF'
    AND mc_entered_by = 'A.ADMIN'
GROUP BY
    mc_id, mc_date_entered;
```

Are you also aware that [DATEDIFF(DD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) only considers the date portion, so there's really no point including the time (if we were still using DATEDIFF)?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the dd issue. I've been switching between dd and minute and dd slipped through.  It should really read minute.

Comment: If you want the query to perform well, you'll still want an index on `mc_date_entered`, and to change your condition to `AND mc_date_entered >= '2012-10-05 20:00:00' AND mc_date_entered < DATEADD(mm,1,'2012-10-05 20:00:00')` assuming the *datetime* comes from some parameter.

Comment: Thanks Richard I'm implementing this, I'd like to accept both answers, but it doesn't allow that unfortunately.  No disrespect to your answer but the other is closer to my issue.